# Can't select rows grouping by created_at

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have the table:

```
+----+----------------------+---------------------+
| id | implemented_features | created_at          |
+----+----------------------+---------------------+
|  1 |                   19 | 2013-07-18 04:10:12 |
|  2 |                    6 | 2013-07-18 04:10:12 |
|  3 |                   26 | 2013-07-19 04:10:12 |
|  4 |                   11 | 2013-07-19 04:10:12 |
|  5 |                    1 | 2013-07-20 04:10:12 |
+----+----------------------+---------------------+
```

When I query this directly via MySQL it works perfectly as I want

```
select date(created_at) as date, sum(implemented_features) as sum from summaries group by date(created_at);
```

But when I try to convert this query to ActiveRecord syntax it returns me nil.

```
2.0.0p0 :035 > Summary.select("date(created_at) as date, sum(implemented_features)").group("date(created_at)")
  Summary Load (0.5ms)  SELECT date(created_at) as date, sum(implemented_features) FROM `summaries` GROUP BY date(created_at)
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Summary id: nil>]>
```

As you see, final queries are equal in both examples. 
Why it don't work in case of ActiveRecord?

Using Rails 4.0.0, Ruby 2.0, mysql db in my rails project.

Comment: I'm not familiar with ActiveRecord, but maybe you need to give an alias to `sum(implemented_features)` like you did in the regular SQL query.

Comment: You say this "doesn't work", but you're not including how it doesn't work. Are you getting an error? What error? Are you getting the wrong results?

Comment: Do you need to include the id in your query for active record? `Summary.select("id, date(created_at) as date, ...`

Comment: Never mind, I see what you mean now. Writing an answer for you :)

Comment: @henrikhodne see the above code. I get ```#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Summary id: nil>]> ```
@Mike, no, I don't need the id's from rows. I tried your example. And get ```#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Summary id: 1>]> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're just a little confused by the console output.

You're saying this:

```
Summary.select("date(created_at) as date, sum(implemented_features)")...
```

so the returned `Summary` instances (wrapped up in an `ActiveRecord::Relation`) don't have any of the usual `Summary` attributes: no `id`, no `created_at`, no `implemented_featured`, etc. When you call `inspect` on an ActiveRecord object, it wants to show you what's inside the object and that means that it wants to show you the contained database attributes; your `Summary` instances don't have any of the usual attributes so you see things like `<Summary id: nil>`.

Fear not, the values you selected really are there. If you say:

```
Summary.select(...).map(&:date)
```

you should see the `date(created_at) as date` values. If you add an alias for the `sum(implemented_features)` then you can extract the sums by using that alias as a method name.