# rails 4 find_by_sql not returning the same results as phpPgAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

when I run

```
             sql = "select count( school_id ) as vote_total,
                  row_number() over( order by  count( school_id ) 
                  DESC ) as rank, school_id
                  from votes
                  where school_id = 111111
                  group by school_id"
```

in phpPgAdmin, I get what I am looking for

```
      vote_total rank school_id
             68    1  111111
```

but when I do the same with Vote.find_by_sql I get

```
     [#<Vote id: nil, school_id: 111111>]
```

I am guessing find_by_sql is not what I should be using. Any idea on  the proper way to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't select rows grouping by created\_at](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17714693/cant-select-rows-grouping-by-created-at)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can get the vote_total and school_id like below

```
sql = "select count( school_id ) as vote_total,
                  row_number() over( order by  count( school_id ) 
                  DESC ) as rank, school_id
                  from votes
                  where school_id = 111111
                  group by school_id"

votes = Vote.find_by_sql(sql)
votes.first["vote_total"] #or votes.first.vote_total
voted.first["school_id"] #or votes.first.school_id
```

Since vote_total and school_id are not attributes of Vote, there are no getter methods defined for those

Comment: The accessor methods actually are there so `votes.first.vote_total` will work. The [`inspect` output, however, only includes model attributes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17714928/479863) so the `vote_total` and `rank` aren't mentioned in `[#<Vote id: nil, school_id: 111111>]`.