# Create a SUM of multiplication columns from distinct tables in Ruby on Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to the following query in Rails:

```
SELECT 
    F.nome AS 'Fornecedor',
    SUM(P.preco * C.quantidade_produto) AS 'Receita Bruta'
FROM compras AS C
    INNER JOIN fornecedores AS F ON F.id = C.fornecedor_id
    INNER JOIN produtos AS P ON P.id = C.produto_id
GROUP BY C.fornecedor_id;
```

I got in the MySQL Workbench:

```
fornecedor               receita_bruta
Bob's Pizza              40
Tom's Awesome Shop      100
Sneaker Store Emporium   50
```

I created the following instance method inside the Compra resource.
    def self.calcular_receita_bruta
        ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all(
            "SELECT
                F.nome AS 'fornecedor',
                SUM(P.preco * C.quantidade_produto) AS 'receita_bruta'
            FROM compras AS C
              INNER JOIN fornecedores AS F ON F.id = C.fornecedor_id
              INNER JOIN produtos AS P ON P.id = C.produto_id
           GROUP BY C.fornecedor_id"
        )
    end

I got this:

```
 => #<ActiveRecord::Result:0x007fe72457cbd8 @columns=["fornecedor", "receita_bruta"], @rows=[["Bob's Pizza", 40], ["Tom's Awesome Shop", 100], ["Sneaker Store Emporium", 50]], @hash_rows=nil, @column_types={}>
```

It works I could do what I need, but is there another way to write this query using some ActiveRecord helpers? For instance:

```
Compra.where(fornecedor_id: 5, product_id: 2)
```

It is just a simple calling for the where method.

I fill that like was making a bad code, writing a directly SQL query like that. Is it ok do the query like that? What the good practices said about it?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Executive summary: `@compras.map(&:fornecedor)`, `@compras.first. fornecedor`, and similar things will give you what you're looking for. Your `Compra` instances only know about the table's columns when you call `inspect` on them but they'll respond to whatever methods you've named in the `select` call.

Comment: Also see [Can't select rows grouping by created_at](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17714693/479863).